# VisualSVN Server service start failure on install or update

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

When I am trying to setup VisualSVN Server in my server. I get error. I can not find any solution.

> Error:  service VisualSVN Server failed to start.
>
> Please check VisualSVN Server log in Event Viewer for more details.

Comment: Please check VisualSVN Server log in Event Viewer. What does it say?

Comment: It is writing in Event Viewer:
Beginning a Windows Installer transaction: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\VisualSVN-Server-2.1.2.msi. Clint Process Id:4504

Comment: Are there any other Error or Warning messages in Event Viewer? The above log entry just indicates that it's starting the actual installation.

Comment: no there is not any error in event viewer :(

Comment: @John, were you able to resolve the problem. I know its too late to comment but thought it will help anyone who faces this issue. I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by reinstalling VisualSVN. Later on I detected the root cause as that Skype was using the PORT that was required by VisualSVN service.

Answer (score 0):

> FYI: there is Knowledge Base article on service start failures, see
>   [**"Troubleshooting VisualSVN Server service start failure"**](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00029/).

VisualSVN Server installation or upgrade can fail with the error:

```
Error: service VisualSVN Server failed to start.
Please check VisualSVN Server log in Event Viewer for more details.
```

If you encounter such issue, I suggest to do the following:

- Verify whether port you specified for VisualSVN Server is available, not in use or blocked. As *@Shant* specified, Skype can use port 443 so VisualSVN Server install may fail if Skype is running. In order to determine, whether any application is already binded to VisualSVN Server's port you can run the following command in elevated command prompt `netstat -anbv`.
- If you do an upgrade and get the service start error, make sure that VisualSVN Server's service account has all required permissions. By default, VisualSVN Server's installer adjust all required permissions automatically. However, if it was installed to a non-default location / repositories are stored on a network share, you may need to configure NTFS / share permissions manually. See [**"Permissions required to run VisualSVN Server"**](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/) for further details.
- If you still can't solve the service start error, I suggest to install / upgrade VisualSVN Server with using the following command line (change MSI filename accordingly):

  `msiexec /i VisualSVN-Server-2.7.2.msi NO_START_SERVICES=1`

  This will allow VisualSVN Server to install without starting it's service. Right after   installation completes succesfully, you can attempt to start the service. When it fails, go to [VisualSVN Server Event Log](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/) to check what errors are logged there. These errors will provide you with helpful clues on the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

While installing this error could occur also if you have given a long repository path . e.g.

```
 'D:\alksdflaskjdflasdjfasdfasdf\kdskdk\adsf\ ....'
```

or also if you have put characters like brackets in the path. e.g.

```
 'D:\Repositories(1)\project1'
```

Try to keep 'Repositories' folder path as small as possible or accept default path.

If above is not helping, go through this [support link here](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00029/).

Answer (score -1):

Just download the latest prebuilt version 3.6.

https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/pre-release/

This has solved the issue as below in 3.5

"asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag"